# A matrix defining a group action on $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a set $$G=\left\{\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0  \\ 
a & b\\ 
\end{array} \right) :a,b \in \mathbb{R} , b \neq 0 \right\} $$
which is a group under matrix multiplication 
and that $$(x,y) \wedge \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0  \\ 
a & b\\ 
\end{array} \right)=(x+ay,by)$$

The orbit of $(0,1)$ gives me $\{(a,b):b\neq0\}$. Why does this give me the plane without the $x$-axis?

The orbit of $(p,0)$ for any $p \in \mathbb{R}$ gives ${(p,0)}$.

Why doesn't the orbit of $(p,0)$ give me everything on the $x$-axis?

Comment: Your question is: "why gives $(a,b)$ with $b\neq 0$ me the whole plane with the $x$-axis removed". I think you can answer this.

Comment: What do you mean by "why"?

Comment: @copper.hat every point on the x axis is in its own orbit.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Thanks for catching that.